# Creating a method to remove ArrayList elements from index x to index y

Tags: java, arraylist, methods

As the title says, if I'm creating a method to remove a section of an ArrayList, how would I go about this.

If I have `ArrayList<Character> se = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g'}`
and want to return only `"abg"`
I would call this method as such:

```
remove(2,5);
```

How could I create this method to remove not only the arg indexes but also everything in between?

Comment: This isn't a coding service. Please post an attempt and ask for help on it.

Answer (score 6):

```
list.subList(2, 6).clear()
```

does the job in one step.

Comment: `subList(2, 6)`; OP wants `[a,b,g]`.

Answer (score 2):

Create a loop counting backward from 5 to 2 and remove the elements.

```
for(int i = 5; i >= 2; i--) ...
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  void method(int startindex , int endindex)
   {  
    for(int i = 0 ; i < endindex - startindex ; i++)//in your example startindex = 2 end.. = 6
     {
       list.remove(startindex);
     }
   }
```

modify your code accordingly.Hope this may solve your problem.

Answer (score 0):

Create a loop at same position, removing elements a certain number of times.

For example, if you wanted to call

```
list.remove(a,b)
```

Your code would be:

```
for (int i = 0; i <= b - a; i++) {
    list.remove(a);
}
```